# How to create nested tiles in Power View

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerview, powerbi, powerquery

I am currently able to use the tile feature in Power View to view data much more quickly. However I haven't figured out a way to have nested tiles to further drill down into the relevant data.

For example, I want a tile strip at the top of my view of all the different "Projects." Once I click on a tile, I want to see all the relevant data for that project and have part of that container have a strip of tiles to show "Risks, Issues, Action Items, etc." and other items in a list. See image in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87tSD.png) (it is a non-working dashboard, but showing you all to get a better idea of the hierarchy).

Does any one know how to do this? I know I can use slicers instead for one of the levels or view filters but I want to be able to use tiles for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a slicer within your tile it will almost do what you want.  However, you wouldn't get the nice icons for warning & error to be the source of selection.  You could make it more visual by separately having a table that includes the images so that when a user selects a slicer value, it shows the appropriate icon. 
HTH,
-Lukasz

Comment: i tried doing this but it doesn't let me add a slicer within the tiled region

Comment: Shoot you're right.  That's not allowed.  Thinking out loud, that if your categories (risk, issues action items) are common across all of your tiles, you could just put the slicer outside the tile and you'd get the right filtering behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the September Power BI update they've added te possibility to: `Drill Up/Down for column and scatter charts` in Reports.

Check out: [Changelog](https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/489224-what-s-new-in-the-latest-power-bi-desktop-update)